Why does the current increase in this circuit?

I have understood the later parts of the model answer, but why does the current increase? I know that the brightness of a lamp is determined by its power which is given by $P=IV$. Since the current increases but the terminal potential difference decreases, what would happen to the brightness? Does the current increase outweigh the decrease in terminal potential difference so that it doesn't matter?

Do you realize that they aren’t showing you the battery internal resistance that is in series with the lamp and bulb resistance.

The key word is, "practical." It means, "not ideal." A first order approximate model of a practical battery is an ideal voltage source in series with an ideal resistor. (We call that resistor the internal resistance of the battery.) The voltage at the terminals of our model—the same voltage that is measured by the meter in your given circuit—is equal to the source voltage minus the voltage that is dropped by the internal resistance. And, Ohm's Law tells us that the voltage dropped by a resistor is directly proportional to the current through the resistor...

...So, as the current goes up, the terminal voltage of our "practical battery" must go down.


but why does the current increases?

The current increases because, while the internal battery resistance (not shown in the diagram) and bulb resistance are considered constant, the lower the variable resistance in series with them the greater the current.

but the terminal pd decreases what would happen to the brightness?

The battery terminal pd decreases because
the more current the battery delivers to the bulb (making it brighter) the greater the voltage drop across the internal resistance of the battery and the lower the pd read by the voltmeter.

is the current increase greater and so the decrease in terminal pd
doesn't matter?

When the variable resistance decreases the current to bulb will increase and the bulb become brighter regardless of the terminal pd. However, the lower the terminal pd, due to a higher internal battery resistance, the less bright the bulb will be.
Hope this helps.

Ok is this correct? @Bob D
(1) As the brightness of the lamp increases the current in the circuit increases because the total resistance decreases
→ The reason we know this has happened is because in order to create greater brightness in the lamp it is a good idea to supply most of the terminal pd to it; this is achieved by reducing the resistance of the variable resistor which also consequently reduces the total resistance in the circuit, thereby increasing the current (This can be understood through the equation $V=I(R_1+R_2 + r)$)

BTW $ R_1$ and $R_2$ just represent either the resistance of the variable resistor and lamp
(2) This means that the current through the internal resistance increases and by V=IR, the lost volts increases
(3) Therefore the terminal pd (which is what the voltmeter acts to measure) decreases
